# React mapping over the same array but rendering different output

Tags: arrays, reactjs, children

I have a case where I need to map over the same array twice in my render method to render different properties of the objects in the array.
So, this is the case:

```
   <Row>
      <Column xs="12" md="6">
        <Row>
          <Column xs="12">
            <Undertekst>
              <FormattedMessage id="InfoPanel.PaymentDates" />
            </Undertekst>
          </Column>
        </Row>
        {getPeriods(payment.periods, periodsDates)}
      </Column>
      <Column xs="12" md="6">
        <Row>
          <Column xs="12">
            <Undertekst>
              <FormattedMessage id="InfoPanel.PaymentAmount" />
            </Undertekst>
          </Column>
        </Row>
        {getPeriods(payment.periods, amount)}
      </Column>
    </Row>
```

So, since I need to map over the same array in two places I have made a function that takes an array and a fuction which will render children element from the current object in the array.

```
const periodsDates = period => `${moment(period .from).format(DDMMYYYY_DATE_FORMAT)} - ${moment(period .to).format(DDMMYYYY_DATE_FORMAT)}`;
const amount= period => formatCurrency(period.amount);
const getPeriods = (periods, children) => periods.map(period => (
  <Row>
    <Column xs="12">
      <Normaltekst>
        {children(period )}
      </Normaltekst>
    </Column>
  </Row>
));
```

I wonder if that is the way to go about this, or is there a better way to solve this, maybe with currying if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new stateless component lets say you call it Periods with 2 props ( periods , data ).
This way you can even use it elsewhere.

Comment: That would be the same, since I would be calling the component two times, and would have the same amount of mapping over the array as I have now.